# Using a 32bit COM object in a 64bit environment

Tags: .net, excel, powershell, 64-bit, ms-office

I'm using powershell 3 on Win7/64bit .
I am trying to use .net of excel (32bit) with this command :
[microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfileformat]
And I got this error:
unable to find type microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfileformat: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
I didn't have this error before when I used Win7/32bit.
Maybe someone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to load the Excel interop assembly like so:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

If you need to use types defined in the Excel interop assembly, you have to load that assembly into PowerShell before you can reference types defined in it.  You're using an enumeration (xlFileFormat) so PowerShell needs the definition of that type.

Comment: So there is no connection between that my office is 32bit and mt environment is 64bit?

Comment: No because the COM server (Excel) runs out-of-process.

Comment: I had this issue as well but every time I ran the script a second time it worked just fine. Turns out I was loading the Excel assembly after it started working on building the spreadsheet. So the first time it would get an error but when I tried it again the Excel assembly was already running and everything worked fine. So, thank you for helping me understand the Powershell Excel commands better, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Had a bit of a similar problem when trying to run the `Redemption.dll` in `PowerShell 64 bit` for `Outlook 2010 32 bit`. This is how I solved it:

```
regsvr32.exe 'C:\path\Redemption.dll'
regsvr32.exe 'C:\path\Redemption64.dll'

$Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    $routlook = New-Object -COM Redemption.RDOSession
    $routlook
    } -RunAs32

Wait-Job -Job $Job
Receive-Job -Job $Job
```

Apparently `Start-Job` has a switch to run a `ScriptBlock` in `32 bit` mode. This works just great for what I need it!